# Fixing "Undefined offset" when working with upload forms

Tags: php, wordpress, file-upload, upload

I'm working on building a file uploader, my first, and am getting an error that (no matter what I do) I can't fix! It is returning an `undefined offset` telling me that there is nothing in the `$_FILES` array ... but I selected photos (it's just not retrieving the data)! Below you will find all the code that appears to relate to this issue. I have tried to debug this on my own but with absolutely no success.

**Update**

After implementing @Dave's suggestions there were no more `offset` errors ... however, the only thing getting sent to the `$_POST` is the `max_file_size` and nothing is getting sent to the `$_FILES` arrays. I have included the return as well as the updated code below.

Here's the return I'm dealing with:

```
// From print_r( $_POST );
Array ( [MAX_FILE_SIZE] => 33554432 [upload] => )    

// From print_r( $_FILES );
array(1) { ["photos"]=> array(5) { ["name"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(0) "" } 
["type"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(0) "" } ["tmp_name"]=> array(1) 
{ [0]=> string(0) "" } ["error"]=> array(1) { [0]=> int(4) } ["size"]=> 
array(1) { [0]=> int(0) } } }

// From var_dump( $_FILES ); just to be sure my bases are covered
array(5) { ["name"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(0) "" } ["type"]=> array(1) 
{ [0]=> string(0) "" } ["tmp_name"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(0) "" } 
["error"]=> array(1) { [0]=> int(4) } ["size"]=> array(1) { [0]=> int(0) } }

// Return from my else showing that $_FILES['photos']['name'] is empty
Nope this doesn't work either!
```

**Here's my code**

HTML form:

```
<form id="photo-upload" method="POST" action="<?php echo plugins_url( 'photo-uploadr/templates/upload.php' ); ?>" enctype="multipart/form-data">                        

    <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="33554432" />               
    <input type="file" id="file-upload" name="photos[]" multiple />
    <button type="button" class="btn" id="pick-photos"><?php _e( "Select Photos to Upload", "shorti" ); ?></button>

    <ul id="file-uploads">
        <!-- The file uploads will be shown here -->
    </ul>

    <button name="upload" id="upload" class="btn upload"><?php _e("Upload", "shorti"); ?></button>

</form>
```

PHP file handler (upload.php):

```
<?php 

require_once( $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/wp-load.php" );
require_once( $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/wp-admin/includes/file.php" );
require_once( $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/wp-admin/includes/image.php" );

var_dump( $_FILES );

if ( !$_FILES ) exit;

// Required for the wp_handle_upload() to upload the files
$upload_overrides = array( 'test_form' => false );

global $current_user;
get_currentuserinfo();
$logged_in_user = $current_user->ID;

// load up a variable with the upload directory
$uploads = wp_upload_dir();

$uploaded = count( $_FILES['photos']['name'] );
for ( $i=0; $i<$uploaded; $i++ ) {
$file_array = array(
    'name'      => $_FILES['photos']['name'][$i],
    'type'      => $_FILES['photos']['type'][$i],
    'tmp_name'  => $_FILES['photos']['tmp_name'][$i],
    'error'     => $_FILES['photos']['error'][$i],
    'size'      => $_FILES['photos']['size'][$i]
);
// this file continues for another 30 lines ... 
// but this is where the error is occuring so why add more?
```

**end Update**

Like I said I am new to uploading files from a form ... I am using [this code](http://matthewaprice.com/upload-image-attach-to-wordpress-post-from-template/) to try and understand uploading ... I'm sure it will be something really simple that I just don't see.

I really need to have this fixed today if at all possible ... any help, however, is appreciated! Thanks

Comment: you're doing it as an extension to wordpress?

Comment: @Dave: Yes, I'm adding this in a plugin I'm currently working on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

give this a  try see if this works its only really a variation but I've had problems with foreach and range previously

```
$uploaded = count($_FILES['photos']['name']);
for ($i=0;$i<$uploaded;$i++) {
    $file_array = array(
    'name'      => $_FILES['photos']['name'][$i],
    'type'      => $_FILES['photos']['type'][$i],
    'tmp_name'  => $_FILES['photos']['tmp_name'][$i],
    'error'     => $_FILES['photos']['error'][$i],
    'size'      => $_FILES['photos']['size'][$i]
    );
    //rest of your logic code here
}
```

Comment: okay, so that completely removed the `offset` error, ... however, I still receiving the empty array at the top of the file and my error message saying that `$_FILES['photos']['name']` is empty. Any ideas?

Comment: try `var_dump($_FILES['photos']);` at the very top of your after `if ( !$_FILES ) exit;` will be fine that'll give you an idea of whats actually being posted in and their array positions.

Comment: I'm still receiving an empty `array`. I did do some more research/testing and tried `var_dump( $_POST );` (which I thought I had already done) which also returns an empty `array`.

Comment: @Designer17 so the main problem is your actual post isn't coming through see my reply on michaels post

Comment: Just had someone point out to me that $_FILES is returning `["error"]=> array(1) { [0]=> int(4)` which is "No file was uploaded."

Answer (score 0):

Because there is 1 file, the following is producing `Array ( [0] => 0 [1] => 1 )`:

```
range( 0, $count_files ) // range( 0, 1 )
```

This is incorrect; the script is trying to find 2 files. You need to change it to:

```
range( 0, $count_files - 1 )
```

Comment: okay, so I changed my range, like you said, but I'm still getting the error ... just it only goes up to `offset: 4` instead of `5` ... ?

Comment: Have you tried `print_r($_FILES)` to see if the data is there?

Comment: Yes, I am doing `print_r($_FILES)` (as well as `var_dump` to make everyone happy). Thanks to @Dave I am no longer getting the `offset` error ... but all that is being returned are empty array's! `print_r`'s looks like this `Array ( [photos] => Array ( [name] => Array ( [0] => ) [type] => Array ( [0] => ) [tmp_name] => Array ( [0] => ) [error] => Array ( [0] => 4 ) [size] => Array ( [0] => 0 ) ) )`.

Comment: looks to me like its not receiving your form post of the files then

Comment: are you using xhtml or html5 ? you may need to do multiple="multiple" on the filebox for the inputs

Comment: @Dave: I'm using html5 ... and I just tried using `multiple="multiple"` just to be safe ... and it still doesn't work. I'm currently trying to research on why they might be empty.

Comment: @Designer17 are you sure your apache instance/process owning user can write to the system temp folder ? it'll return a blank array if the system cannot store the files in the temp folder

Comment: @Dave: Here are the permissions returned when I check the MAMP/tmp directory `drwxrwxr-x` ... from my limited knowledge on the matter this means I have the correct permissions, right?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46281/discussion-between-designer-17-and-dave)

Answer (score 0):

I think you must iterate till $count_files - 1, because if you upload 1 file your foreach loop will currently execute twice.